# Kernel and Image of Linear Operators

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let A and B be linear operators from vector space V to vector space W.
>   Prove that
>
> 1) Ker(A) $\subset$ Ker(B) $\iff$ $\exists$C: W$\to$W such that CA = B
>
> 2) Im(A) $\subset$ Im(B) $\iff$ $\exists$D: V$\to$V such that A = BD

I had an idea to use factor spaces V/Ker(A) and V/Ker(B) but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you a hint 
For the indirect implication it is immediate for both assertions 
for the direct implication and for the first one take a basis of the kernel and complete it to the whole space V and use the fact that a linear map is totally defiened in a basis 
same thing for the seconf assertion